# SQL - Linking two tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I need to that;

Now, We have two tables. I want to set foreign keys each table. But at this point, there is something like this. On both foreign keys, it will be linked to the opposite table. In other words, the foreign1 column in table A will be connected to the foreign1_ref column in table B, the foreign2 column in table B will be connected to the foreign2_ref column in table A.

Example SQL Table:

```
Table: A
+--+--------+------------+
|ID|foreign1|foreign2_ref|
+--+--------+------------+

Table: B
+--+--------+------------+
|ID|foreign2|foreign1_ref|
+--+--------+------------+
```

How can I make that?
Thanks.

Comment: Let's start with "why do you need this"? What are you trying to accomplish that wouldn't work with a foreign key in a single table only?

This only works if at least one foreign key can be null

Comment: What problem are you having? As @mk1x86 said, it should work fine if one of the FK is nullable. To avoid a chicken-and-egg problem, when you have mutually referencing rows in the two tables, you have to create the first one with a null FK, then create the second one referencing it, then you can update the first FK.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foreign1` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foreign2_ref` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_foreign1_b1_idx` (`foreign1`),
  KEY `foreign2` (`foreign2_ref`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_foreign1_b1` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign1`) REFERENCES `b` (`foreign1_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign2` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foreign1_ref` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `foreign1` (`foreign1_ref`),
  KEY `fk_foreign2_a1_idx` (`foreign2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_foreign2_a1` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign2`) REFERENCES `a` (`foreign2_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```